# javascript from codeigniter into jsp

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, jsp

I have method javascript in codeigniter but when i try to put it into jsp, the javascript doesn't work. In codeigniter, if i call the function, the page will refresh, but when i try put the code into my jsp, the function doesn't refresh the page.

the code like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submit_page(from){
    var doc = document.frm_data;        

    if(from == 1){
        doc.tipe_lst.value = "";
        doc.cab2_lst.value = "";
    }else{
        doc.wil_lst.value = "";
        doc.cab_lst.value = "";
    }

    doc.action = "<?php echo $page_action;?>";
    doc.target="";
    doc.submit();                           
}
```

I call it from codeigniter like this:

```
<form name="frm_data" method="post">

<div style="float:left; position:relative; width:350px;">
    <div>
        <label>Kantor Wilayah : </label>
        <select name="wil_lst" onchange="submit_page(1);">
            <option value=""></option>
            <?php if(!empty($main_unit)){?>         
            <?php foreach($main_unit as $theitem): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $theitem->KDWIL;?>" <?php if($unit == $theitem->KDWIL) echo "selected";?>><?php echo $theitem->UNIT_BESARAN;?></option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Kantor Cabang : </label>
        <select name="cab_lst" onchange="submit_page(1);">
            <option value=""></option>
            <?php if(!empty($sub_unit)){?>
            <?php foreach($sub_unit as $theitem): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $theitem->UNIT_BESARAN;?>" <?php if($subunit == $theitem->UNIT_BESARAN) echo "selected";?>><?php echo $theitem->UNIT_BESARAN;?></option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </div>  
</div>

<div style="float:left; position:relative; width:350px; padding-left:20px; border-left:1px solid;">
    <div>
        <label>Tipe Cabang : </label>
        <select name="tipe_lst" onchange="submit_page(2);" style="width:300px;">
            <option value=""></option>
            <?php if(!empty($tipe_cabang)){?>           
            <?php foreach($tipe_cabang as $theitem): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $theitem->STATUS_CABANG;?>" <?php if($tipe == $theitem->STATUS_CABANG) echo "selected";?>><?php echo $theitem->STATUS_CABANG;?></option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Kantor Cabang : </label>
        <select name="cab2_lst" onchange="submit_page(2);">
            <option value=""></option>
            <?php if(!empty($sub_unit2)){?>
            <?php foreach($sub_unit2 as $theitem): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $theitem->UNIT_BESARAN;?>" <?php if($subunit2 == $theitem->UNIT_BESARAN) echo "selected";?>><?php echo $theitem->UNIT_BESARAN;?></option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>



</form>
```

and when i try to put it into my jsp, the page doesn't refresh or send the action of function submit_page like this:

```
<form name="frm_data" method="post">
    <div class="row">
        <form role="form">
        <div class="col-md-5 well bg-default">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="a">Kantor Wilayah</label><br/>
                <select tabindex="1" name="tipe_lst" class="chosen-select" 
                        style="width: 240px;"   
                        onchange="submit_page(1);">
                    <option value="">Pilih</option>

                    <c:if test="${not empty main_unit}">
                       ${main_unit}
                    </c:if>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <select tabindex="1" name="cab_lst" onchange="submit_page(1);"
                        class="chosen-select" style="width: 350px;">
                    <option value="">Pilih</option>
                    <option value="1">KANTOR CABANG BALIGE</option>
                    <option value="2">KANTOR CABANG UTAMA TANJUNG BALAI ASAHAN</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5 well bg-default">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="a">Tipe Cabang</label><br/>
                <select tabindex="1" class="chosen-select" style="width: 240px;" name="a" id="a">
                    <option value="">Pilih</option>
                    <option value="1">KANTOR WILAYAH MEDAN</option>
                    <option value="2">KANTOR WILAYAH PADANG</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <select tabindex="4" class="chosen-select" style="width: 350px;" name="d" id="d">
                    <option value="">Pilih</option>
                    <option value="1">KANTOR CABANG BALIGE</option>
                    <option value="2">KANTOR CABANG UTAMA TANJUNG BALAI ASAHAN</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 well bg-greensea">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="c">Pencarian Pegawai
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input01">
                </label>                        
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-rounded btn-slategray btn-md">Search</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</form>
```

the page doesn't refresh. how to fix it?

Comment: how did you altered `doc.action = "<?php echo $page_action;?>";` to work in jsp?

Comment: @madalinivascu it works on codeigniter, my problem is, the code is doesn't works on jsp using spring framework

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use jsp code instead of PHP in java script

```
doc.action = "<?php echo $page_action;?>";
```

Comment: no i mean, it doesn't works on jsp using spring framework, not in php